# How port, channel and interface are working together?

Tags: switch, etherchannel, interface

I do know about Physical port but a little knowledge about channel and interface, can any one explain how these 3 work simultaneously, i am not getting proper idea and from cisco i got to know about LACP but first i have to know the basic part. Thanks Everyone

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

802.3ad Link Aggregation serves to bond multiple, individual physical interfaces into a single, logical virtual interface: a "port-channel".

The virtual interface of the port-channel controls the traffic across all interfaces which are members of it. Think of the port-channel being the supervisor and the individual interfaces being the employees: the port-channel tells everyone else what to do.

Understanding the underlying code and mechanisms that Cisco uses to perform this task is outside the scope of your studies. The following document should suffice:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2sb/feature/guide/gigeth.html